# ExecuteScript does not execute func described in html and which are run after page has been loaded

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, webdriver

There is Silenium server, NUnit, WebDriver.

I have C# dll with following code:

```cs
private IWebDriver driver;

// ...

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

// ...

[Test]
public void test()
{
    string testURL = "file:/C:/Tests/test.html";
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(testURL);
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    object resFunc = js.ExecuteScript("open_form");
    object res = js.ExecuteAsyncScript("alert('hello')");
}
```

File `test.html` looks like:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./test.js"></script>
</head>
<body unselectable="on">
</body>
</html>
```

And `test.js`

```js
function open_form () {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

I run test with console NUnit and when "hello" appears, background color is not changed.
How can I run functions which are within html and which are making some actions?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the parentheses.

Make it:

```
    object resFunc = js.ExecuteScript("open_form()");
```

Which, by the way, you don't *actually* need to use the return value from this function.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped to run scripts! But it remains to solve the problem with the arguments. 
So when I pass arguments to the function and output the alert, the parameter passed as undefined

int dec = 10;
string value = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return open_form()", new object[] { dec });


function open_form (val) {
 alert(val);
 return val;
}